# How can I run a mklink system command (cmd.exe) from a delphi 7 aplpication

Tags: delphi, command-line, cmd, command, symlink

In my application at runtime I want to run the cmd line Mklink /d (link location) (actual file/folder location).

So far I have:

```
symLink := PChar('/d C:\Data\'+fileName+' N:\"Database Archives"\'+fileName);

ShellExecute(0, nil, 'Mklink', symLink, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

but I have also tried:

```
symLink := PChar('Mklink /d C:\Data\'+fileName+' N:\"Database Archives"\'+fileName);

ShellExecute(0, nil, 'cmd.exe', symLink, nil, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
```

Am I along the right lines? 
Is there any documentation to explain each parameter required by `ShellExecute`?

Comment: MSDN doc for [ShellExecute function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: ShellExecute is used to call an app and optionally passing some parameter to the app: this is not your case. As far as I know, you have to use pipes to write commands into a `cmd` window

Comment: If you want to create a link shortcut, you may find [How to create a file shortcut (*.lnk file) on desktop in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704265/how-to-create-a-file-shortcut-lnk-file-on-desktop-in-windows) interesting

Comment: I know the command line i want to execute, i just need to know how to perform it in Delphi

Comment: @fant No need for pipes, just pass the command as an arg, and hope that you can quote it properly!!

Comment: @DavidEffernan ok, I got it: #2 `symLink := PChar('/C Mklink /d "C:\Data\' + fileName + '" "N:\Database Archives\' + fileName + '"');` I was not aware of `/C` thanks

Comment: yes but how do i pass a command as an arg to cmd.exe from delphi 7

Comment: also @fantaghirocco i am not creating a .lnk file to my desktop, i am backing up a database schema to a seperate server then creating a symbolic link to the program files to trick MySQL to believing it is a file in its own program files therefore making the files accessible to all applications accessing that mysql database

Comment: `/C` and a proper use of doublequotes does the trick: see above my reply to David Effernan

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to run command line from Delphi?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3378896/how-to-run-command-line-from-delphi)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply put, don't do this. Use the API. It's called [`CreateSymbolicLink`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363866.aspx). Pass the `SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY` flag.

This is much more robust and allows you to report errors properly, cope with systems that don't have `cmd.exe` and so on.

Do note that creating symbolic links requires the process to be elevated. I trust you already know that. Do also check for errors as described the linked documentation.

More broadly you'll need to reconsider the specific paths in your question. You cannot make cross volume symbolic links.

As regards documentation, these are Windows functions. Just type the name into a search engine and you will find the MSDN docs.

---

In an older Delphi you'll need to define the function because the supplied header translations don't have it.

```
const
  SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY = $00000001;

function CreateSymbolicLinkA(
  lpSymlinkFileName: PAnsiChar;
  lpTargetFileName: PAnsiChar;
  dwFlags: DWORD
): Boolean; stdcall; external 'kernel32';

function CreateSymbolicLinkW(
  lpSymlinkFileName: PWideChar;
  lpTargetFileName: PWideChar;
  dwFlags: DWORD
): Boolean; stdcall; external 'kernel32';
```

Comment: is it possible to get this API for delphi 7?

Comment: Sure. You can call any Win32 function from Delphi 7. You just might need to declare it yourself. Give me a minute to edit.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan why is it recommended not to use the cmd line method? i will only be creating a symbolic link from 1 server to 1 machine that runs a database.

Comment: You won't be able to check for errors and you'll invoke a whole command line interpreter so that it can call CreateSymbolicLink. Did you read my comment about cross volume links?

Comment: I don't understand the negative implications of creating cross-host symbolic links? or is this not possible with the CreateSymbolicLink API?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan what is the purpose of dwFlags in the function CreateSymbolicLinkA

Comment: That's explained in the documentation, to which I linked. Rather than me repeating it, how about you try to read and understand it, and come back if you are unsure. I'd like to help you learn how to use MSDN docs.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan yeah sorry i read it and seen its for whether it is a directory, using SYMBOLIC_LINK_FLAG_DIRECTORY as the third parameter and using the function still does not create my symbolic link though.

Comment: Well, next step is to check for errors. Again, see the docs to learn how. I trust your process is elevated. And I trust you aren't trying to make a cross volume link.

Comment: Brilliant I got your solution working. Thanks for your time!

Comment: i pretty much had the error checking previous to creating the symlink, it is the last stage of a monthly backup procedure

Comment: That's not what I mean. Did you capture and check the value returned by CreateSymbolicLink?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I will be doing that today, not delete the local backup if creating the symlink was unsuccessful, write to log and re instantiate the hard copy.